# Что значит Link DLL и With Runtime Package?

Tags: c++builder, dll, компиляция

Для нормальной компиляции требуют снять галочки у этих параметров, но что они значат никто не знает. Причем если комплировать приложение под х64, то появляется ошибка "Out of Memory", "Exited with code 2". Почему?